# How to render multiple solid cut planes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, objective-c++

I'm rendering some cut planes to do solid capped clipping using stencils in OpenGL. Each cut plane works fine by itself, but I want to be able to create multiple cut planes at the same time. The problem I'm running into is when I cut an object with a second cut plane, in certain view orientations there are no back faces to use to create a stencil to draw the capping plane. I know there must be some way to work with multiple stencil buffers to get what I want, but I just can't think of the right way to do this. I figure it will probably involve saving the stencil buffer for each clipping plane situation, then clipping those stencil buffers using the clipping planes. Anyone know where I should go with this? For anyone not familiar with the capped solid clipping plane method I'm referring to, it can be found at the following links:

http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=269481