# Any way of rendering multiple solid cut planes?

Tags: algorithm, opengl, 3d, glsl, mesh

Is there any way of rendering multiple solid cut planes in OpenGL?

With solid "cut plane" I mean a plane that cuts away parts of a mesh and fills the hole with, for example, a solid color. This gives the impression of the mesh being solid instead of only a shell.

The classic approach to render this using a single cut plane is to reject samples on the invisible side of the plane, and then use the stencil buffer to count the number of front and back faces in the remaining mesh.

However, I can't figure out how to extend the algorithm to work with multiple cut planes. Like this case for example:

```
     e
    ___
   /   \
  |  A  |
  |     |
----------- a
  |  C  |
  |     |
----------- b
  |  B  |
  |     |
   \___/

     d
```

Cut plane 'a' removes the part 'A' from the mesh.
Cut plane 'b' removes the part 'B' from the mesh.
The remaining, visible part of the mesh, 'C' is rendered from location 'd' in the direction e - d (looking at 'e').

The problem is that no fragments will be generated for pixels inside of 'C' since both the entry and the exit points are removed by the cut planes.

I would really like to avoid having to slice the actual mesh since the cut planes can change location every frame.

I think this is them same question that is asked here some years ago:
[How to render multiple solid cut planes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4495134/3967883)

Comment: Just my personal opinion but I'd prefer a "slice" operation on a mesh (returning a new mesh) on the CPU rather than trying to work with an "effect" on the GPU.  Longer term it'll be more versatile and flexible.

Comment: I agree with Robinson. The solution you're talking about is a "render trick". You can't use a render trick if you have no geometry to render (because it is cut on both sides). The best approach is to generate additional geometry in the whole where your mesh was cut. The algorithm should be quite straight forward.

Comment: Yes, I will look into this as a second option. The algorithm might not be that complicated, but I fear that it would be quite time consuming to implement compared to some "render trick".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, arbitrary CSG trees can be rendered using stencil buffer techniques. A very good introduction is given here: ftp://ftp.sgi.com/opengl/contrib/blythe/advanced99/notes/node22.html

Comment: Thank you! I haven't implemented the algoritm yet, but it looks like it does what I'm asking for.